# Change Primary keys from int to guid in existing database

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have taken over a project with an existing SQL server installation. The client wants to move everything to the azure SQL and make several on premises databases sync to azure.

The PK's in the tables are int's and for the Azure datasync to work PK's needs to be guid's. the database consists of several related tables.

My question is therefore. What is the best way to change the PK's to guids and at the same time update the FK's accordingly in existing tables.

The process as far as I see it:
1. Create new guid column
2. fill it with ID's.
3. change the PK to the guid column
4. update data to new guids in the FK tables.

Is there an easy scriptable way to make this magically happen?

Comment: You know what need to be done and also have a pretty good plan, I would say. Go ahead and do it, there is no easier way of doing it unfortunately.

Comment: Well you are correct. There are 20+ connected tables. So I would rather find an automated method. Something like looping through connected databases. But I do not have enough experience in SQL queries, to now the limits

Comment: There is way to make this happen automagically. Even if there was I wouldn't trust. Especially with only 20 tables. I would suggest that you find a column other than your new guid to use as the clustered index.

Comment: What is problem if you include another GUID column and keep the old one as well? Use the old system for reference and GUID for the cloud.

Comment: The GUID has to be the primary key to merge tables with Data sync. So just adding a guid column will not make it work.

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing built into SQL Server that makes this any easier than the process you described already.